# jQuery offset() vs. css()

Tags: jquery

Consider the following code for changing the position of an element:

```
myElement.css({top: '100px'});
myElement.offset({top: '100'});
```

According to [this benchmark test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-offset-vs-css) `.css()` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/css/)) quite handily outperforms `.offset()` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)).

Why is this? How does offset position the element differently from the css top declaration, and why does this method appear to be slower?

Comment: @C-link he is comparing two methods, not the real CSS, see the `.` before `.css()`

Answer (score 0):

As the doc says, you can use `.offset()` for getting and setting the coordinates to elements.

`.css` changes the style which includes setting top/left too.

And When it comes to performance, `.offset()` is faster than `.css`.

See **[jquery-offset-vs-css](http://jsperf.com/jquery-offset-vs-css)**

Comment: According to the link (which was already part of my question) `.offset()` is slower not faster. The question is, why is the setting of coordinates through `.offset()` slower than changing the styles with `.css()`? How exactly do the two different methods work?